# How to print the position of a value in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm using a for loop to search for the smallest value present within an array and printing that value out. I want to print out what position that value is in in the array (0-9), how would I do this?

```
int smallest = array[0];

for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
    if (smallest > array[counter]) {
       smallest = array[counter];
    }
}

printf("The smallest value stored within the array is %d", smallest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need another variable (initialized "0") in which you store the value of "counter" each time the if condition is true like below:

```
int smallest = array[0];

int position = 0;

for (counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
     if (smallest > array[counter]) {
       smallest = array[counter];
       position = counter;
  }
}

printf("The smallest value stored within the array is %d and position = %d", smallest, position);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, that got it working, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @FarzadSalimiJazi, it's not about who's faster, but who helps the OP understand better.

Comment: Are you serious !!! What exactly make you understand better in his post !! its just a counter!! the name of variables are just different! He talk about being fast and I just answered it! You should be smart enough to understand that was just a comment ! No worry about that, I just saw the post and answered! @StoryTeller

Comment: I suggest you calm down. And stop shouting!!!!!!!! The OP obviously understood the above post better, since it didn't just edit the code, but also provided an explanation first. It's a hallmark of good answers here.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this !

```
int smallest = array[0];
int index  = 0;
for (counter = 0 ; counter < 10; counter++) {
    if (smallest > array[counter]) {
       smallest = array[counter];
       index = counter;
    }
}

printf("The smallest value stored within the array is %d in %d", smallest, index);
```